# O que significa Tweeted em uma pergunta?

Tags: suporte, histórico-de-revisões

Ao ver o histórico de edições [desta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/86493/revisions), fiquei curioso com a parte escrita:

> Tweeted twitter.com/#!/StackOverflowPT/status/642533462419841024

Como mostra a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao acessar o link, podemos ver que o twitter foi feito com o usuário **StackOverflowPT**.

Minha dúvida é:

**Foi um bot do SOpt que fez esse tweet? Se sim, qual o critério para ele realizar o Tweet?**

Comment: Eu é que não fui :p

Comment: Posso colocar o link da revisão que aparece isso?

Comment: @jbueno Já está ali "desta pergunta".

Comment: Ah, verdade. É ruim de ver os links aqui no meta, eles tinham que ter outra coisa que não cinza.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quando o robô posta no twitter (provavelmente via API), ele informa isto para na pergunta para que você possa acompanhar, acaso use twitter. No meu caso eu uso e sigo o [@StackOverflowPT](https://twitter.com/StackOverflowPT).

O robô posta (detalhes https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183410/198279):

- Perguntas interessantes do site principal (tem que ter o total do score >= 1, contando negativos e positivos)
- Perguntas que recebem recompensa
- Pergunta fechadas não são enviadas, a não ser que tenham uma recompensa
- E postagens do META que também são consideradas interessantes

  > Ainda não sei o que qualifica para uma questão do META, acredito que basta ter o score >= 1, ou ter a tag [destaque](/questions/tagged/destaque), mas ainda não pude ter certeza

> **Nota:** estou editando esta pergunta pra colocar os requisitos para que o BOT poste no twitter

Comment: Mas é realmente o robô que posta? Existe algum critério para isso?

Comment: @Randrade não me recordo, mas existe sim um critério, tanto que já vi "coisa errada" postada lá. Vou editar assim que encontrar a postagem que li isso, era no METÃO ou codinghorror.